# A question about uniform partition and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I'm doing a exercise related to uniform and (Darboux/Riemannian) integrability and I encountered a problem in my proof. I hope anyone could give me some hints for it. This is my problem :

Let $I=I_1\times\cdots\times I_n\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a $n-$rectangle and $\mathcal P(I)$ is the set of all partition of $I$. Let $f:\, I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a bounded function.
For each $P,\,Q\in\mathcal P(I),$ we denote $\|P\|$ is the maximum length of edges of all subrectangles corresponding to $P$. If we write $P=P_1\times\cdots\times P_n$ where $P_i$ is a partition of $I_i$, then we let $PQ=(P_1\cup Q_1)\times\cdots\times(P_n\cup Q_n)$ be the refinement of both $P$ and $Q$.

Here is what I'm trying to solve : $\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0:\ \forall P\in\mathcal P(I)$ such that $\|P\|<\delta,$ we have
\begin{align}
0\leq U(f,P)-U(f,PQ)<\varepsilon
\\ 0\leq L(f,PQ)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon
\end{align}

My attempt : given $\varepsilon>0$, let
\begin{align}
C&=\sup_I|f|
\end{align}
I will prove for the $U(f,P)$ case, the $L(f,P)$ case is the same.
\begin{align}
U(f,P)-U(f,PQ)&=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\big(\sup_Rf\big)|R|  - \sum_{S\in H(PQ)}\big(\sup_Sf\big)|S|
\\ &\leq\sum_{R\in H(P)}\big(\sup_R|f|\big)|R|  + \sum_{S\in H(PQ)}\big(\sup_S|f|\big)|S|
\\ &\leq C\sum_{R\in H(P)}|R|+C\sum_{S\in H(PQ)}|S|
\\ &\leq C\sum_{R\in H(P)}\|P\|^n+C \sum_{S\in H(P)}\|PQ\|^n
\\ &\leq C\big|H(Q)\big|\|P\|^n+C\big|H(PQ)\big|\|PQ\|^n
\end{align}
After get here, I have no idea how to show the inequality $<\varepsilon$ using $\delta$.

I really hope anyone could guide me to solve this. Thank you.